# Textview bounds UIImageView out of the View

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, constraints

I'm trying to rebuild the twitter post tweet feature as well as the UI. I'm currently at the point that, when I type something long in the `UITextView`. My selected image that I want to tweet get bounds out of the container view that is in a scrollview.

See this example:

[image]

The blue background is the scrollview background and the grey background is the container views background. I can't scroll too.

My UIImageView has initially 0 height and is directly attached to the top of the textview.
I change the height of the UIImageView with their constraint:

```
// sets the image
let newHeight = self.postedImageView.getImageHeight(forImage: image)
self.postedImageViewHeightConstraint.constant = newHeight
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
self.postedImageView.showImage(image)
```

How can I make this the scrollviews contentView height to grow as I type something in the textview so it doesn't get bounds out the view?

These are my constraints:

[image]

Update:

With the postedimageviews bottom constraint added to the content views bottom

[image]

Comment: Can you update the project link?. It would be easier to fix bugs :D

Comment: You have to make sure your imageview's top is pinned to the textview's bottom and imageview's bottom is pinned to the scrollview's bottom.

Comment: in order for scroll views to work properlly, they require a single view inside (conventionally called content view). Inside that content view if you have a textView setup, the screen should expand and automatically expand with the text you type and should be able to scroll with it. -OuterView -> ScrollView ->ContentView->TextView, hard to show structure in comments

Comment: @JulianSilvestri exactly I have that structure but it doesn't expand.

Comment: hmmmm, have you set the scrollview height to be greater than or equal to the text view ?

Comment: @JulianSilvestri I can't find it. I updated my question with a picture with my current constraints

Comment: @AjinkyaSharma Yes but then the image view itself is too big and not directly on the bottom on the textview. The image is somewhere in the middle of the uiimageview

Comment: @jsbeginnerNodeJS what are the constraints for the textview? I think you should break down component by component, and try small things at once. Try creating a scrollview in a sample storyboard, add components one by one. There is some minor mistake over here which you are missing. Start over with a clean slate, you'll get there.

Comment: @AjinkyaSharma You can see the constraints in my updated question. But does the scrollview normally grow when the views inside the contentView grows?

Comment: Yes it does grow, but what I don't see in you constraints is (maybe I am missing something), that your imageview is not pinned to the bottom. So I don't know how does your scrollview knows how much content height it needs. The logic here is that, your scrollview should know how much content height it will need. Does your text view expand as you keep typing, or does it scroll with the same height? If it does expand, it should somehow tell that to the scrollview, like change in its content size should tell the scrollview to update its content size. Hope I am helping you and not confusing you :-p

Comment: Yeah the bottom constraint was missing, but now the content view is very small and when I show the image, the scrollview is somehow scrollable even than the content view is still visible on the screen.

Comment: Thank you so far. See my updated question

Comment: It **only** happens to scroll when I add the image.

Comment: try adding in: scrollView.height >= textView.height -> Constraint

Comment: @JulianSilvestri still the same issue. Btw the scrolling is also enabled when I make some enters in the textview although the content view isn't bigger than the screen

Comment: I am noticing now that you also have a collection view. Your strucutre shows (unless i am reading it wrong) Outerview -> scrollView -> ContentView & CollectionView -> TextField... This may be causing your issue as you have a content view as well as collection view. The contentView should be the ONLY subview of the scrollView. All other views should be subviews of the CONTENTVIEW. Try moving your collection view inside your ContentView.

Comment: My collection view isn't inside the scrollview. It is on top on the scrollview so it doesn't conflict.

Comment: This is getting too big of a discussion, I would suggest you to create a sample project and upload it on git. Might as well look into it and push it back for you :-p

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/SwiftiNewling/testpicturesscrollview/src/master/

Comment: Hi @jsbeginnerNodeJS , just checked your project, everything works perfectly. I think the extra space at the bottom is because at least in teh project that you uploaded, the bottom constraint of the content view to scrollview is 308. It should be 0. I would suggest that there is no need to give a 0 height to image and calculate it after. Instead give a desired height or aspect ratio to you imageview or set a dummy image(in storyboard), and let the imageview calculate the height for itself when you set an actual image.